# Issues in pig latin translator

Tags: c#

I'm new to Stack Overflow and coding in general. I'm taking an object oriented programming course and am trying to learn C#. It's my second week in the course and my prof wants me to create a pig latin translator. Unfortunately, he's got some funky requirements that I'm struggling with. The basic Pig Latin part I think I have but I'm struggling with these issues:

- If a word starts with the letter Y, the Y should be treated as a consonant. If the Y appears
  anywhere else in the word, it should be treated as a vowel.
- Keep the case of the original word, whether it’s uppercase (TEST), title case (Test), or lowercase
  (test).
- Keep all punctuation at the end of the translated word.
- Translate words with contractions. For example, can’t should be an’tcay.
- Don’t translate words that contain numbers or symbols. For example, 123 should be left as 123,
  and Jim!@# should be left as Jim!@#.

Here is my code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String english = txtInput.Text;
        string piglatin = "";
        string firstletter;
        string restofword;
        string vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";                       
        int letterpos;

        foreach (string word in english.Split())
        {
            firstletter = word.Substring(0, 1);
            restofword = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
            letterpos = vowels.IndexOf(firstletter);
            if (english.Contains("1"))
            {
                txtTranslation.Text = english;
                break;
            }
            if (english.StartsWith("y"))
            {
                piglatin = piglatin + " " + restofword + firstletter + "ay";
                txtTranslation.Text = piglatin;
                break;
            }
            if (english.StartsWith("Y"))
            {
                piglatin = piglatin + " " + restofword + firstletter + "ay";
                txtTranslation.Text = piglatin;
                break;
            }

            if (letterpos == -1)
            {
                piglatin = piglatin + " " + restofword + firstletter + "ay";
            }
            else
            {
                piglatin = piglatin + " " + "way";
            }

            txtTranslation.Text = piglatin;
            txtInput.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void txtTranslation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

In regards to any that contains numbers or symbols or the like, I feel like I could make a lot of if statements that say: if (english.Contains("1"))

```
txtTranslation.Text = english;
break;
```

and just do this for 1 -9 but I believe there has to be an easier way. Same thing if symbols are used. I also came up with something similar for handling the letter Y but I believe that isn't necessary the best solution either.

I'm stuck on maintaining the casing of translated words and on keeping punctuation at the end of a translated word.

Comment: I must admit, the hardest part about this question is the wording, it lack specificity and quite frankly overly verbose and odd. Can you put some examples like `"Hey there"` => `"Eyhay heretay"` `"Cash Me Outside"`  => `"Ashcay Emay utsideay"`

Comment: You started off right, so keep going with that.  Go with it, case by case.  Look at what your process is, and try to repeat that.  In your case, you always start off the same.  If it's empty, return empty.  Otherwise, grab the first letter, and the rest of the word.  (btw, you can change rest of the word to word.substring(1)) .  From there, build up a case for Don't Translate: var dontTranslate = ['1','2',3'...'@','#'] .  Check if word index of any dontTranslate . Also, your case of Y and y are the same case, so you can combine those.  When you do substring, it will keep casing.  Keep at it